# Text not displaying over image CSS HTML JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I created a "slideshow" of three images that cycle through every 5 seconds. The javascript works as expected, but the text that is associated with each image is not displaying over the image.

index.html

```
<div class="image-container">
  <div class="image-container__slides image-container__slides--fade">
    <div class="image-container--text">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Provident
      error voluptatem voluptas neque dolor incidunt perspiciatis facere ab
      ipsam expedita.
    </div>
    <picture class="image">
      <source
        srcset="./assets/images/couple-large-hi-dpi.jpg 5168w"
        media="(min-width: 1380px)"
      />
      <source
        srcset="./assets/images/couple-large_1920.jpg 1920w"
        media="(min-width: 990px)"
      />
      <source
        srcset="./assets/images/couple-medium_1280.jpg 1280w"
        media="(min-width: 640px)"
      />
      <img src="./assets/images/couple-small_640.jpg" alt="" />
    </picture>
  </div>

  <div class="image-container__slides image-container__slides--fade">
    <div class="image-container--text">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Consequatur
      alias placeat atque animi aut. Explicabo cum facere laudantium ratione
      rem!
    </div>
    <picture class="image">
      <source
        srcset="./assets/images/men-large-hi-dpi.jpg 5168w"
        media="(min-width: 1380px)"
      />
      <source
        srcset="./assets/images/men-large_1920.jpg 1920w"
        media="(min-width: 990px)"
      />
      <source
        srcset="./assets/images/men-medium_1280.jpg 1280w"
        media="(min-width: 640px)"
      />
      <img src="./assets/images/men-small_640.jpg" alt="" />
    </picture>
  </div>

  <div class="image-container__slides image-container__slides--fade">
    <div class="image-container--text">
      Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nihil
      consequatur voluptates, cupiditate mollitia quidem quod illum cum nisi
      dolore quam?
    </div>
    <picture class="image image--last">
      <source
        srcset="./assets/images/person-large-hi-dpi.jpg 5168w"
        media="(min-width: 1380px)"
      />
      <source
        srcset="./assets/images/person-large_1920.jpg 1920w"
        media="(min-width: 990px)"
      />
      <source
        srcset="./assets/images/person-medium_1280.jpg 1280w"
        media="(min-width: 640px)"
      />
      <img src="./assets/images/person-small_640.jpg" alt="" />
    </picture>
  </div>
</div>
```

**css:**

```
    .image-container {
      position: relative;
      & > div img {
        width: 100%;
      }
    
      &__slides {
        display: none;
    
        &--fade {
          img {
            opacity: 1;
          }
        }
      }
    
      &--text {
        position: absolute;
        background-color: #333;
        top: -50%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      }

}
```

**ImageSlider.js**

```
class ImageSlider {
  constructor() {
    this.slides = document.querySelectorAll(".image-container__slides");
    this.slideIndex = 0;
    this.showSlides();
  }

  showSlides() {
    let i;
    // Display all images as none
    for (i = 0; i < this.slides.length; i++) {
      this.slides[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    this.slideIndex++;
    // Check to see if the slideIndex is higher than number of images
    if (this.slideIndex > this.slides.length) {
      this.slideIndex = 1;
    }
    // Assign one image to be displayed
    this.slides[this.slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
    // Cycle through images every 5 seconds
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.showSlides();
    }, 5000);
  }
}

export default ImageSlider;
```

What i'm trying to do is display each text over the correct image. I thought that if i display "block" it would show the text but it doesn't. Any help would be appreciated thanks

Comment: You need to set a `z-index` property on your text element.

Comment: yah, the important is z-index. Try this in your css: `z-index: 999` for any tag you want on top

Comment: should the index go into the `image-container--text` class?

Comment: Yes. Try using `z-index: 5;`.

Comment: That does not work. Also tried a z-index of 999

Comment: I can get the content to display above the image (not over the image like i want) by using `display: content` in the `image-container--text` class

Comment: Added an answer - you have a couple things incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things going on:

1. You need to set the `z-index` on the `--text` element.
2. You have `top: -50%` which moves your text UP out of your element. It should be `top: 50%`;

```css
.image-container {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.image-container > div img {
  width: 100%;
}

.image-container--text {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #333;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index: 5;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-container">
  <div class="image-container__slides image-container__slides--fade">
    <div class="image-container--text">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Provident error voluptatem voluptas neque dolor incidunt perspiciatis facere ab ipsam expedita.
    </div>
    <picture class="image">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/640x640" alt="" />
    </picture>
  </div>
</div>
```